# How to add title in custom select menu in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

i am using custom select menu of jquery mobile framework.While reading the docs i found that i can add title in two ways-

- By Adding data-placeholder="true" in one option(This works but for select menus having less options say 5 to 10)
- Another is using label, but it make the whole text of label as a title of select menu..

But in this case i am getting `Country*:` as a title of select menu, but it should be `Country` only...
How can i do that?
Any one having any idea?
Here is code which i am trying...

```
<lable for="a1">Country*:</lable>
<select  data-native-menu="false"  id="a1" >
      <option>blah</options>
      </select>
```

Comment: I am curious to know if label is coming as the title of the select menu because I just tried an example and there the label did not come as the title.Can you please post a sample of your code here.

Answer (score 3):

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/selects/

> **Placeholder options**
>
> It's common for developers to include a "null" option in their select
>   element to force a user to choose an option. If a placeholder option
>   is present in your markup, jQuery Mobile will hide them in the overlay
>   menu, showing only valid choices to the user, and display the
>   placeholder text inside the menu as a header. A placeholder option is
>   added when the framework finds:
>
> An option with no value attribute (or an empty value attribute) An
>   option with no text node An option with a `data-placeholder="true"`
>   attribute. (This allows you to use an option that has a value and a
>   textnode as a placeholder option). You can disable this feature
>   through the selectmenu plugin's hidePlaceholderMenuItems option, like
>   this:

```
$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.hidePlaceholderMenuItems = false;
```

It looks like the smaller lists use the placeholder option and the larger lists use the label. This might be due to how the page is displayed.

> When the select has a small number of options that will fit on the
>   device's screen, the menu will appear as a small overlay with a pop
>   transition.
>
> When it has too many options to show on the device's screen, the
>   framework will automatically create a new "page" populated with a
>   standard list view for the options. This allows us to use the native
>   scrolling included on the device for moving through a long list. **The
>   text inside the label is used as the title for this page.**

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/HGBQc/2/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <span>The No Value Option<pre><code><option>Choose a State...</option></code></pre></span><br />
        <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Your state:</label>
            <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu="false">
                <option>Choose a State...</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>


        <br />

        <span>The Placeholder Option<pre><code><option value="choose-one" data-placeholder="true">Choose one...</option></code></pre></span><br />
        <label for="select-choice-3" class="select">Your state:</label>
            <select name="select-choice-3" id="select-choice-3" data-native-menu="false">
                <option value="choose-one" data-placeholder="true">Choose one...</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>

        <br />
        <span>Smaller Option</span><br />
        <label for="select-choice-6" class="select">Shipping method:</label>
        <select name="select-choice-6" id="select-choice-6" data-native-menu="false">
            <option value="choose-one" data-placeholder="true">Choose shipping...</option>
            <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
            <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
            <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
            <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When the select has a small number of options that will fit on the device's screen, the menu will appear as a small overlay with a pop transition.

When it has too many options to show on the device's screen, the framework will automatically create a new "page" populated with a standard list view for the options. This allows us to use the native scrolling included on the device for moving through a long list. The text inside the label is used as the title for this page.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was to add a second label (#__label_cboBancoR8), destinated to be visible to user, and preserve the original label (#label_cboBancoR8) for the select. Something like this:

```
div id='contenedor_cboBancoR8' class='bloque select-opt mb20'>
    <label id='__label_cboBancoR8' class='select'>BANCO</label>
    <label id='label_cboBancoR8' for='cboBancoR8' class='select'>Selecciona tipo de banco</label>
    <select name='cboBancoR8' id='cboBancoR8' data-native-menu='false' data-transition='none'>
    <option value='-1' data-placeholder='true'>Selecciona tipo de banco</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Later we hide the original label:

```
$('#label_cboBancoR8').hide();
```

The result was:

[image]

and

[image]

Well... hope it helps to someone with the same problem.